# Markdown editor with which I can embed handwritten notes and edit them

Tags: open-source, html, ubuntu, note-taking, markdown

I extensively use markdown to take notes and render it in Html or PDF (using Pandoc). I have a Wacom stylus. And I want to take hand-written notes (specifically, lecture notes).

I want to embed these in the markdown such that it can be rendered (at least in HTML, would be great if it does in PDF also). Also, I would like those files to be embedded in an editable format. Preferably I don't want to use binary formats. And, would like open formats.

It would be OK if the handwritten notes were just embedded as images, but I am hoping to have option to edit those notes. I'm using Ubuntu 18.4.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please detail how you need to edit embedded notes? For instance can it let you draw on the images, or call an external image editor?

Comment: I would like the handwritten notes to be edited in its native software, which supports tools for handwritten notes (like xournal). I would use the stylus to create and edit the notes.